# Как заставить axios работать на iOS7 (iPhone 4)?

Tags: javascript, ios, ios7, axios

Делаю авторизацию gj Wifi. Из айфонов под рукой только iphone4. Хочу его как самую старую поддерживаемую платформу заявлять. Но и технологии современные тоже неплохо бы иметь. Так вот axios не работает. Vue работает.

Нажимаю на кнопку "проверить" - запрос не прилетает. Может есть известные полифилы или настройки babel?

Сейчас настроенно так:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3,
    "targets":{
        "browsers": "> 1%, not dead"
    }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Заклинание бы чтоб не подбирать процент вручную.

Comment: Пробовали? А то интересно. Просто мы, к примеру, давно решили выбросить поддержу iPhone 4 и Android 4.0 (:

Comment: это было перед тем как задал вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, нужно полифилить всё самому. В вашем случае, скорей всего, на iOS тупо не работают ES6 штуковины. И, вполне вероятно, не работают промисы.

Попробуйте заполифить промисы, как [описано в доках axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#es6-promise-polyfill).

Если речь про babel, то смотреть [тут](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill/).

Comment: babel не помог, `require('es6-promise').polyfill();` вставил после babel - заработало

Comment: @eri видимо, не до конца заработало)